# mysql alternative to AES for encryption - so can't decrypt value

Tags: mysql, encryption, cryptography, aes, md5

I'm currently using AES encryption in mysql (in a Silex PHP app) and would like to change to using a form of encryption where we can't decrypt the value - in order to lessen liability concerns.  I believe the MD5 can be used for this purpose, but I've read that MD5 is not terribly secure.  Is there an approach that you'd suggest?

Comment: There are lots of hash functions and many of them are better than MD5. Depending on the data that you want to hash, a single hash function might even not be enough. For example, passwords should be hashed repeatedly using PBKDF2, bcrypt, script or Argon2 with a lot of iterations / high cost factor. What's your data?

Comment: What are you encrypting? Hashes are not encryption, they are one-way non-reversible. Is the question is about passwords you need to use iterated-salted-hashing.

Comment: We want to encrypt the passwords but not have the ability to decrypt them since people often use the same passwords for various sites and we don't want to risk someone (e.g. an  internal employee) getting a user's password.  With a mongodb project, we are accomplishing encryption this way, but I wasn't sure what is the best practice for mysql.

Comment: AES is a symmetric-key encryption standard. As such it is not a hashing mechanism. You probably already know this.

Comment: to reiterate above: don't hash or encrypt passwords, that's a bad idea. use a KDF